# Trying to determine differences in one column

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 columns and I'm trying to determine the differences in one of the columns.  Here is an example:

```
drug_id      ndc              item_id
1          12345678910        1234
1          12345678910        1235
```

There are multiple drug_id's and each drug_id has multiple ndcs.  (A particular ndc could appear in multiple drug_ids).  Essentially, I want to find where there is a difference in item_id based on the drug_id and ndc.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` should work.

SELECT DISTINCT D.Drug_ID, D.ndc, D.item_id
FROM Table d;

If you're unfamiliar on SQL Predicates, you can learn more about them [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/distinct_vs_distinctrow/unique_values_records.asp) for Access specifically.